# Backup all web files from VPS

Tags: linux, bash, cron, backup, vps

I have a VPS, there are tens websites and I need to make a regular backups, let´s say twice in a week (sunday 11pm and Wednesday 11pm).

I have only minimal experience with server management, and user exp. with Linux (I tried to play with linux for 2 years).

The files I need to backup are in /var/www/hosting/webXX/www/ dirs (XX means web1, web2, ... web50). EDIT: in webXX dir is more dirs, I need only this one (www).

I tried to find a bash script for that, but with no result. In bash scripting I have no exp. Then I only call the script with cron.

On Mondays and Thursday I´d like to download one zipped file to my computer (manually, if it won´t be possile automatically).

Thanks.
Roman

**EDIT**:
okey, I tried solutions without bash.
In command line via ssh,

```
ssh root@server '( cd /var/www/hosting/web*/www/ && tar cfz - . )' > backup.tar.gz
```

It´s not automatically (like bash script), I have to start that manually.

**Problem:** it takes me only the first web, not recursively all of them.

Any idea?

Comment: If you have access through SSH to your VPS you could try connecting with FileZila with SFTP with your SSH user data, like this you will be able to download manually the files you need. In case you need the backups because it's the development of a website, you should consider using a code repository and doing backups of your entire VPS so you can save as well databases, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I´m using FileZilla now, but there is more problems: 1. my edit above, from each website I need to download (or zip) only one folder (www), nothing else. The second thing, I need to do that during night, regarding to server speed. I really looking for bash script, no manual doanloading files via FileZilla.

Comment: So I need to specify the dir (files to download) as /var/www/hosting/web*/www/*, which isn´t possible in FileZilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
tar czf backup.tar.gz `ls /www/hosting | grep \.com$ | sed 's/$/\/www/g' | sed 's/^/\/www\/hosting\//g'`
```

Comment: hm, I´ve tried ssh root@server 'tar czf backup.tar.gz `ls /var/www/hosting | grep ^www`' and it returns me "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive". Path is okay, I´ve checked that more times.

Comment: the whole command I wrote incl. single-quotes before "tar" and after "www". Syntax hightlighter ate me that there :-( It should be: `ssh root@server 'your_code'`.

Comment: Try creating a script on your VPS with my code inside it, and running it.

Comment: The same error, when I try to run it from PuTTy via ssh (I logged into VPS and run your command). "Cowardly refusing to crate any empty archive."

Comment: Sorry, mistyped the command. Try it again.

Comment: Okay, it works better, but takes ALL subdirs for each web. I need only WWW (there are more dirs, I don´t need them). Tried to use `grep -E ^web(.*)/www` with no success.

Comment: I forgot about the www part, let me know if the new command works

Comment: Still the same error. I´m on the second server, where the structure is /www/hosting/DOMAIN/www/ (DOMAIN is variable - example.com, example1.com, whatever.com, ..., all domains ends ".com"). Tried to run " tar czf backup.tar.gz `/www/hosting/ | grep \.com$ | sed 's/$/\/www/g'`" (without quote marks of course). I tried the backslash before ".com", slash after "hosting". With no success.

Comment: It has to be 

    tar czf backup.tar.gz \`ls /www/hosting | grep \.com$ | sed 's/$/\/www/g'\`

Comment: My fault, I think I tried that correctly, just a mistype here. I add you an image, still doesn´t work. http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=tar.png

Comment: Maybe this? `tar czf \`ls /www/hosting | grep \.com$ | sed 's/$/\/www/g' | sed 's/^/\/www\/hosting\//g'\``

Comment: Still nothing, but we have another error message. And I attach newer screenshot: http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=tarlil.png. Really appreciate your effort!

Comment: I voted up for one of previous comments, but it wasn´t solution. Problem is still here, as I wrote 11 hours ago. I forgot to close quotes and it seemed to do something.

Comment: I forgot to specify the output file

`tar czf backup.tar.gz \`ls /www/hosting | grep \.com$ | sed 's/$/\/www/g' | sed 's/^/\/www\/hosting\//g'\``

Comment: That's great! Once again big thank you! I´ve just added **P** after `czfP`

Comment: Richard, is there any way how to call that within cron? I have a few cron actions and give to cron a .sh script. Do I need to create new bash script which only content will be this tar command, or I can give him directly this tar?

Comment: @Roman you can do this directly, but it will be difficult because of the quotes. It would be safer to use a script

Comment: so create a new bash script where the only content will be this `tar`?

Comment: Yes, that would be my recommendation

Comment: Thanks, no other question from me :-)

Comment: I´ve returned to my previous server, there are data stored in `/var/www/clients/clientX/webX/www` (where both X are numbers). I tried `tar czfP backup.tar.gz \`ls /var/www/clients | grep ^client | grep ^web | sed 's/$/\/www/g' | sed 's/^/\/var\/www\/clients\//g'\``. I expected problem is in usign `grep` twice this way.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, because the `ls` will only return the stuff in /var/www/clients, which is your list of clientX, you are going to need something with `find`. `find` will recurse through the directories and print out every subdirectory and file. Try `tar czfP backup.tar.gz \`find /var/www/clients -type d -maxdepth 3 | grep -E '/var/www/clients/client[0-9]+/web[0-9]+/www'\``

What is happening, is `find` will print out all directories in /tmp/www/clients to a max depth of 3, which is what we need, clientX/webX/www

Comment: I´ve created a bash script (b.sh) with this line (and `#!/bin/bash` before, of course). If I call directly this script, `sh b.sh` it creates me a backup tar file. When I call cron, in `crontab -e` I have `30 * * * * /var/www/b.sh`, no file is created. Any idea?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

tar czfP x.tar.gz \`find /var/www/clients -type d | grep -E '/var/www/clients/client[0-9]+/web[0-9]+/www'\`` - between first and second line are two enter, of course. What's wrong? Paths are okay, I've checked that. And when I call that directly, the file is created.

Comment: Cron's working directory is the home directory of the user it is running as. Who's crontab is that?

Comment: I´m logged as root, in crontab I have `30 * * * * /var/www/b.sh`, in b.sh is the `tar` row with relative path (tar czfP backup.tar.gz). When I change it to absolute (/var/www/backup.tar.gz), no change.

Comment: Is the script executable?

Comment: :-), now it is. Fine, thanks.

Comment: And really last question (then I remove this topic from my bookmarks). Is it possible to exclude one website, eg. `/var/www/clients/client2/web2/`? There are some old backups, unused data, it my "sandbox" with many GB which I dont need regularly download. The rest websites of client2 should stay in backup (eg. `client2/web4`), the same another clients.

Comment: `tar czfP x.tar.gz \`find /var/www/clients -type d | grep -E '/var/www/clients/client[0-9]+/web[0-9]+/www' | grep -v 'client2/web2'\``

If you have any more questions, feel free to email me at alfonzo1955 <at> gmail.com